# Objective C - Format TextField as Currency with Decimals While Typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm trying to get currency formatting while typing working, however I'm having some trouble with the following code block:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{

    if (textField == self.withdrawAmount) {

        NSString *noCurrencySign = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
        NSString *textFieldText = [noCurrencySign stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[textFieldText floatValue]]];

        textField.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", formattedOutput];
    } 
}
```

This works fine if the user enters any non-decimal number (ex, 284928 formats to 284,928). However, if the user enters 284928. (with the intention of eventually making it 284,928.50),  the decimal place is stripped out.

What am I doing wrong :)

Comment: Don't use `float`, use `double`.

Comment: FYI - this code will fail miserably in locales that format their numbers differently. Never assume a specific currency symbol or grouping separator.

Comment: I think what you want is [NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumberformatterstyle/nsnumberformattercurrencystyle?language=objc)